# OER text for the mathematics of fair division

Tags: textbooks, course-design

I'd like to design a course with a unit on fair division, and I'm looking for an OER text to use. The course will be a general education seminar, so students won't be expected to have any mathematical background beyond high school. Thus, I'm looking for a very accessible text suited for a beginning learner. I've done some basic searches and found a few resources, but they are hard for me to assess for my purposes, and am hoping someone here can recommend something to me based on their experience. Thank you!

Comment: Are you looking to cover fair division, broadly, or would specific applications suffice? I'm aware of some texts -- like [this one called "Math in Society"](https://spot.pcc.edu/math/mathinsociety/chap_five_apportionment.html) -- that cover apportionment of representatives in the US House or delegates in (Democratic) presidential primaries.

Comment: What is an OER text?

Comment: OER stands for Open Educational Resources.  Typically these materials are downloadable without cost.  Often they are contributed by teachers, perhaps in contrast to ones developed by vendors.   They may be openly licensed as source, which makes it easier to adapt the work to your class, or over time, and offers some assurance that they will not just disappear.

Comment: @BrendanW.Sullivan: Thanks for the reference! And good question. I'm looking for a broad treatment of fair division - Ideally the text would be robust enough to cover about one-third of a semester course.

Comment: My math economist friend highly recommended books by Steven Brams (from NYU). They do not seem to be OER, but she said that Steven is a nice guy to whom you can write directly and see if he has some free online material posted somewhere too. You can also check his webpage at https://as.nyu.edu/faculty/steven-brams.html

Comment: @fedja: Wonderful! Thank you so much for this reference. Very helpful. I think I have access to his books via my institution, so I can use them to plan my course. Perhaps I can list his books as recommended resources so students can consult them if they want.